# I have an small (74k) svg which balloons in size (over 8MB) when packaged for an app clip -- how to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, apple-appclips

Included a new version of an small (74k) svg and the app packaging process causes it to balloon. The "map" file is small but the asset catalogue is ridiculous:

```
  {
    "AssetType" : "Image",
    "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
    "ColorModel" : "RGB",
    "Colorspace" : "srgb",
    "Compression" : "deepmap2",
    "Encoding" : "ARGB",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "map",
    "NameIdentifier" : 1261,
    "Opaque" : true,
    "PixelHeight" : 1600,
    "PixelWidth" : 2000,
    "RenditionName" : "map-content-20220921.svg",
    "Scale" : 1,
    "SHA1Digest" : "F6B627AC4B42F3075182878BFD55BED5C6A0245F1EAB499B0D7B0DE58E549B66",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 845935,
    "Template Mode" : "automatic"
  },
  {
    "AssetType" : "Image",
    "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
    "ColorModel" : "RGB",
    "Colorspace" : "srgb",
    "Compression" : "deepmap2",
    "Encoding" : "ARGB",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "map",
    "NameIdentifier" : 1261,
    "Opaque" : true,
    "PixelHeight" : 3200,
    "PixelWidth" : 4000,
    "RenditionName" : "map-content-20220921.svg",
    "Scale" : 2,
    "SHA1Digest" : "16CBC41B8D815092652A57E5EB7A51FC0FB3779534BB284B79B45E1784FBCAD8",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 2587011,
    "Template Mode" : "automatic"
  },
  {
    "AssetType" : "Image",
    "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
    "ColorModel" : "RGB",
    "Colorspace" : "srgb",
    "Compression" : "deepmap2",
    "Encoding" : "ARGB",
    "Idiom" : "universal",
    "Name" : "map",
    "NameIdentifier" : 1261,
    "Opaque" : true,
    "PixelHeight" : 4800,
    "PixelWidth" : 6000,
    "RenditionName" : "map-content-20220921.svg",
    "Scale" : 3,
    "SHA1Digest" : "229B85A485005131707584BC8349DC6FB4E6A51442E277194955B1F7C7DE0B50",
    "SizeOnDisk" : 5563794,
    "Template Mode" : "automatic"
  },
```

I see that there are compression settings but "off" is not one of them.

Any guidance appreciated.

ps: partial report above generated by running
`xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info Assets.car`
on the asset file in the app clip's .ipa file

Comment: Looks like it creates several bitmap (e.g. jpg/png) thumbnails in different sizes?

Comment: Yes, except they aren't thumbnails, they are full-size renders -- and are large!